# pytest: printing from fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I'm writing tests using Pytest. I have a fixture like this:

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(autouse=True, scope='session')
def manage_tests():
    print("Do stuff...")
    do_stuff()
    yield
```

I put a print statement there so I could see it in the console when I'm running the tests, for better visibility into what the program is doing. But I don't see that text in the console, I'm guessing pytest swallows it. Is there any way to print from a fixture?

Answer (score 17):

Pytest doesn't not swallow the output, it's just not shown by default. To see output in console, try running test with `-s` option, like:

```
pytest -s <path_to_file>
```

Answer (score 11):

with pytest 3 use this fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def tprint(request, capsys):
    """Fixture for printing info after test, not supressed by pytest stdout/stderr capture"""
    lines = []
    yield lines.append

    with capsys.disabled():
        for line in lines:
            sys.stdout.write('\n{}'.format(line))
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see a print statement. But there are a couple of important things to note:

- Because you have `scope=session`, this is only executed during the first test.
- If the first test passes, nothing will be printed out. You can force the stdout to printed anyway (==not captured by pytest) by using the command-line option [-s](https://pytest.org/latest/capture.html).